# How to enlarge a picture in a picturebox

Tags: c#

I want to click a button to enlarge the picture in a picture box. How can I do that?

Comment: lolz.. that's near perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for but I think you'll find the control presented in this CodeProject article useful:

[A scrollable, zoomable, and scalable picture box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScalablePictureBox.aspx)

The control extends PictureBox and adds a number of nice features, such as zooming and panning using a context menu and a 'thumbnail view' window.

If you can't use the control itself I'm sure you;ll benefit from studying the source.